# What's wrong in MR?

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I run a MR program in CDH cluster, finally shows successful and output files successful ,but a lot error in the beginning:

[image]

[image]

and here are my codes:

```
    Configuration hdfsConf = new Configuration();
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs");
    hdfsConf.set("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs");
    String jobName = "AIAD-MR";
    Job job = Job.getInstance(hdfsConf, jobName);
    Path path = new Path(inputDirPath);
    Path path1 = new Path(outPath);
    FileSystem fileSystem = path.getFileSystem(hdfsConf);
    FileSystem fileSystem1 = path1.getFileSystem(hdfsConf);
    if (fileSystem.exists(path)) {
        FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, path);
    }
    if (fileSystem1.exists(path1)) {
        fileSystem1.delete(path1, true);
    }
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outPath));
```

Comment: You might want to add some commentary on what analysis you have already done on the errors, and what questions you have.

Comment: looks like a connection error, which is not related with mapreduce. Does your program run in all cluster nodes, or just the master?

Comment: My program run only on the master.